# Android game loop lag increases drastically over time

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

I am making this simple 2D canvas game using SurfaceView for android and am having this problem with my game loop: the fps immensely lowers as time goes on. I found the design for the game loop from this article: [deWiTTERS Game Loop](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/).

GamePanel.java

```
package jacobmahoney.guardianofearth;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MainThread thread;
    private SpaceshipObject spaceship;
    private LeftCircle leftCircle;
    private RightCircle rightCircle;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    public GamePanel(Context context) {

        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
        getScreenSize(context);
        spaceship = new SpaceshipObject(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        leftCircle = new LeftCircle(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        rightCircle = new RightCircle(screenWidth, screenHeight);

    }

    public void getScreenSize(Context context) {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getRealSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            retry = false;
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        rightCircle.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        spaceship.draw(canvas);
        leftCircle.draw(canvas);
        rightCircle.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

MainThread.java

```
package jacobmahoney.guardianofearth;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private boolean running;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 50;
        int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
        int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;

        long next_game_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int loops;

        long prev = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (running) {

            Log.d("MainThread", "" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - prev)); // this value drastically increases over time
            prev = System.currentTimeMillis();

            loops = 0;

            while (System.currentTimeMillis() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
                this.gamePanel.update();
                next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
                loops++;
            }

            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**

After commenting out all the instances of the game objects: leftCircle, rightCircle, and spaceship **completely** from GamePanel.java, I didn't have the issue where the game gets increasingly laggy over time, which I guess is obvious. Then when I put just the spaceship game object back into the mix, the game still got increasingly laggy over time, but at a smaller rate than it was when I had all three game objects drawing to the canvas.

I am completely stumped, I have literally no idea what could be causing this... any ideas?

**EDIT2:**

*removed*

**EDIT3:**

Found out what the issue was. It was a problem with the code I was using to draw paths for each object. I forgot to place a *path.reset()* and *path.close()* before and after the code I used to draw the path. Also I removed my edit2 because I made a comment in the heat of my frustration, that was unwarranted.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak to me. You could monitor your app's memory usage through Android Studio -> Android Monitor window -> Memory (use Dump Java Heap button to save a heap dump), and see which objects tend to build up but are never cleared.

Comment: Your surface created is being called several times. Because of navigating or something else changes lifecycle. Nothing to wrong with it. But you shouldn't crate another thread, or at least pause the old instance that still runs in background and trying to work on main thread which blocks your UI thread.​

Comment: @EmreAktürk Creating a new thread is fine, so long as the old one is properly ended.  But this doesn't particularly seem like great code to me.  I'm not sure what the purpose of the inner loo is-  it allows the panel to be updated multiple times per frame, but no matter how many times it updates only the last will be drawn to screen.  Seems like a waste of rendering to me.

Comment: And at a minimum, isRunning needs to be set as volatile, or it may not be updated on the game loop thread properly.

Comment: altskop, I tried to use the Memory Activity Monitor and "Dump Java Heap" button, but don't understand too much about heaps to understand the analysis. emre-aktürk, I have no idea what you are talking about. gabe-sechan, the article I posted explains the game loop and I'm not sure what the point of setting the "running" variable to volatile would be because the variable won't be be getting modified by different threads.